# Sequence of events leading up to cancellation of context

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

In the below program, there is a select sequence in both `C1` & `C2`. A deadline context for 1.5 seconds is defined in `C1`, which after the deadline, cancels the context, leads to `ctx.Done()` and prevents the reading of integers in `C2` which would further cancel the context and lead to `ctx.Done()` in `C1`.

If that is the case then what use is `cancelCtx()` in `C1` when the context is already being cancelled?

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    C1(ctx)
}
func C1(ctx context.Context) {
    deadline := time.Now().Add(1500 * time.Millisecond) 
    ctx, cancelCtx := context.WithDeadline(ctx, deadline)
    printCh := make(chan int) 
    go C2(ctx, printCh)
    for num := 1; num <= 3; num++ {
        select {
        case printCh <- num:
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Printf("C1: Finished\n")
        }
    }
    cancelCtx()
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}
func C2(ctx context.Context, printCh <-chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case num := <-printCh:
            fmt.Printf("C2: %d\n", num)
        case <-ctx.Done():
            if err := ctx.Err(); err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("C2 Error: %s\n", err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("C2: Finished\n")
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to cancel the context manually before deadline, for example in case of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs for `context.WithDeadline()`](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithDeadline):

> Canceling this context releases resources associated with it, so code should call cancel as soon as the operations running in this Context complete.

So best practice is to call `cancelCtx()` (or whatever you call the function) as soon as you no longer need it (it's [fairly common](https://go.dev/blog/context#the-server-program) to `defer cancel()` even if this means it's called multiple times).

In your example there is another reason that this might be beneficial. Lets assume that the deadline is configurable and has been increased to 5 seconds; now cancelling the context leads to the termination of `C2` being triggered by the call `cancelCtx()` instead of waiting until the deadline ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/rICWHBTpT7j)).

Comment: Does the `cancelCtx` function run after the `ctx.Done` in `C1` or `C2`?

Comment: That depends upon which example you are asking about (whether the deadline applies or the loop in C1 exits because `num = 3`).  In my example the context is cancelled by the `cancelCtx()` (so that must be before the `C2` `<-ctx.Done()` fires). In your original code `cancelCtx()` will run after the deadline expires (so the `C1` `<-ctx.Done()` has definitely fired prior to that); the order of the `cancelCtx()` and `C2` `<-ctx.Done()` is undefined (it could happen in either order). Hopefully that answers your question?